# Ivy dependency primefaces 3.5 will not resolved

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces, liferay

I used to date the followind dependency

```
<ivy-module
    version="2.0" ...>

<dependency name="primefaces" org="org.primefaces" rev="3.5" />
```

but since today the dependency is not resolved correctly. I tried it with the newest version

```
<dependency name="primefaces" org="org.primefaces" rev="5.1" />
```

and this works fine.

I went to the direct-download page of primefaces (http://www.primefaces.org/downloads) and there stands:

> PrimeFaces 4.0 and newer are available at Maven Central, for older
>   releases add the following repository definition to your pom.xml in
>   repositories section.
>
> ```
> view plainprint?
> <!-- For 3.5 and older -->  
> <repository>  
>     <id>prime-repo</id>  
>     <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
>     <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
>     <layout>default</layout>  
> </repository>
> ```

Is this an actual news? If so, how I have to change the dependency line in ivy to get the version 3.5 ? This version 3.5 ist necessary for me for Liferay portlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add that repository as Ivy resolver. If you don't have it yet, create `ivysettings.xml` with something like this inside

```
<ivysettings>
    ...
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="primefaces" root="http://repository.primefaces.org" m2compatible="true" />
    </resolvers>
    ...
</ivysettings>
```